# An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.2.7), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, bundler

I am receiving an error message while trying to use Jekyll with Bundler. The error message reads as follows:

```
extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/mgl/my-jekyll-website/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7
for inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/mgl/my-jekyll-website/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-22/2.6.0/eventmachine-1.2.7/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.2.7), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.2.7' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  jekyll was resolved to 4.3.2, which depends on
    em-websocket was resolved to 0.5.3, which depends on
      eventmachine
```

What steps can I take to resolve this error and successfully use Jekyll with Bundler?