ruby 2.6.10p210: An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.2.7), and Bundler cannot continue
I use ruby 2.6.10p210 on mac os sonoma 14.6.1.
I ran following bundler command for a jekyll-blog:
bundle install

bundler failed with this error:
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/bundler/gems/extensions/universal-darwin-23/2.6.0/eventmachine-9cb13a8a6236/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/bundler/gems/eventmachine-9cb13a8a6236 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/bundler/gems/extensions/universal-darwin-23/2.6.0/eventmachine-9cb13a8a6236/gem_make.out

  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:99:in `run'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:47:in `block in build'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tempfile.rb:295:in `open'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:29:in `build'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:185:in `block in build_extension'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:235:in `mon_synchronize'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:181:in `build_extension'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:229:in `block in build_extensions'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:226:in `each'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:226:in `build_extensions'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/installer.rb:830:in `build_extensions'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:71:in `build_extensions'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/source/path/installer.rb:34:in `post_install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:244:in `generate_bin'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:194:in `install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in `install_from_spec'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in `do_install'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in `block in worker_pool'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.3.9/lib/bundler/worker.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.2.7), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  minimal-mistakes-jekyll was resolved to 4.24.0, which depends on
    jekyll-feed was resolved to 0.17.0, which depends on
      jekyll was resolved to 4.3.4, which depends on
        em-websocket was resolved to 0.5.3, which depends on
          eventmachine


the mkmf.log is the following :
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX15.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX15.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
   24 | #include "ruby/config.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX15.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: note: did not find header 'config.h' in framework 'ruby' (loaded from '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks')
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"pkg-config --exists openssl"
package configuration for openssl is not found

Based on the contents of mkmf.log, it seems like there is an issue related to OpenSSL, but I’m not sure how to resolve it.

Check your question—you have pasted the same error output twice, and it seems you meant to paste the contents of mkmf.log instead.

I would never recommend using the system ruby for development, instead I would recommend installing a ruby version manager, rvm is my go to but theirs also others. This will allow you to install modern versions of ruby (Ruby 2.6 reached EOL in March of 2022). While your issue may very well be openssl related, it can easily be resolved by using a supported version of ruby.

OP of the other question with this title also uses ruby 2.6 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76486927/an-error-occurred-while-installing-eventmachine-1-2-7-and-bundler-cannot-cont). Try rbenv as mentioned by @engineersmnky and I would strongly recommend using ruby 3.x which comes with many benefits.
